# Regex exclude words from greedy matches value

Tags: regex

Input:

```
:CITYNAMEONE SCHEDULED
:CITY NAME TWO
:CITYNAMETHREE
```

Tried:

```
:([A-Z\s]+)(?=SCHEDULED)
:([A-Z\s]+)(?:SCHEDULED)?
```

Expecting:

```
CITYNAMEONE
CITY NAME TWO
CITYNAMETHREE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the capital letter genre and to consume only
words that are not SCHEDULE this is ideal

```
:(?:\s*(?!SCHEDULED)[A-Z]+)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/3GefdG/1

```
: 
(?:
  \s* 
  (?! SCHEDULED )
  [A-Z]+ 
)+
```

If need to trim white space at the beginning as well, , a capture group is needed.

```
:\s*((?!SCHEDULED)[A-Z]+(?:\s*(?!SCHEDULED)[A-Z]+)*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/dmcXpQ/1

```
: 
\s* 
(                     # (1 start)
  (?! SCHEDULED )
  [A-Z]+ 
  (?:
    \s* 
    (?! SCHEDULED )
    [A-Z]+ 
  )*
)                     # (1 end)
```

Comment: Well done. Thank you for the Capture Group example. As of today I don’t understand the amount of code required for the capture group version to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
:(.*?)(?=\s*SCHEDULED|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2qq0Io/1).

*Details*:

- `:` - a colon
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*SCHEDULED|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespaces or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.